# tcp rst from separate host

Tags: bash, tcp, scripting, network-programming

I'm looking for something that allows me to block certain connections (based on the IP of the destination) from a central location.

I'm basically running Security Onion and a copy of the full network is being sent to eth1. I was wondering if it's possible for (maybe iptables) monitor eth1 until a specific DST IP is found and perform a tcp reset on that connection. As far as I was able to find out, the package dsniff (in debian) has tcpkill which should be able to perform this.

Any tips or pointers appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You try just implementing a firewall rule? I know a firewalld `--rich-rule` on centos/rh would work. On debian it might be `sudo ufw deny to {ip-address-here} to any`. Not sure if the `deny to` statement works, I just altered a command found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-block-an-ip-address-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-linux-server/).

Comment: My objective is to have a host in the network that can disrupt the connections of other hosts, based on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

"My objective is to have a host in the network that can disrupt the connections of other hosts, based on the destination"

**Answer #1: MitM**

Ok so lets say you have three computers connected like so:

```
A <--------------------------> B <--------------------> C 
   192.168.1.2    192.168.1.1     10.0.0.1      10.0.0.2
```

Lets say you turn `B` into a Linux Router by installing a Linux distro and setting the sysconfig variable `ip_forward` to `1`. Then you tell `A` to route traffic to `C` via `B` and vice versa. If you turn `B`'s firewall on you can then implement firewall rules that 'disrupt' traffic between `A` and `C`. One firewall rule can be "if packet destined for `C` deny it".

You are basically implementing a [MitM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You could also probably do this with [Ettercap](https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/), but that can often be way more complex.

**Answer #2: Sniff and Spoof**

Without a MitM position you have to rely on Sniffing and Spoofing. In the diagram below `B` will have two connections, the Span port for sniffing traffic and a LAN connection to Spoof packets from either `A` or `C`.

```
              B
             ^  ^
            S|  |
            P|  |
            A|  |
            N|  |
   A<----->|Switch|<----->C
```

*Sniffing*

The Span port is sending packets to `B`. They are most easily viewed if a raw socket is opened (see more info [here](http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd-part-2/)). Using the raw socket you filter traffic yourself and create handlers for events.

*Spoofing*

I think it is again easiest to implement a raw socket and fabricate your own TCP RST message, setting the proper layer 3 and layer 2 information and then sending it out the LAN connection.

I think both of these can be accomplished with Scapy, but I have only used it for [spoofing](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: See what you mean. Makes sense. In my setup, I don't have traffic going via a router. I basically have a span port (for a network IDS) that sends my NIDS all traffic. What I wanted was to be able to initiate a TCP RST from the NIDS just by being in the same network. Basically, MitM without actually being in between the two hosts.

Comment: Ok, updated the answer, short answer is check out Scappy. I guess you could also ARP Poison, but at that point you are implementing a layer 2 MitM.